# Can we check which installed apps are using camera and microphone using corona(by only using lua)?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to create an app which checks which available apps are using camera or microphone and display the list of it on the app screen.And which app uses most of camera/microphone.

Can any one please help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah i tried everything but it doesn't work. 
Thanks ldurniat